Why do various materials have different specific heat capacities?
What physically determines the specific heat capacity of a material? Is there a combination of factors that determine this? For example what gives water an uncharacteristically high specific heat capacity? In general what determines a materials specific heat capacity?

The different degrees of freedom in which energy may be distributed through the material determine the heat capacity. For example, a molecule may move in three spatial directions, that's three different degrees of freedom. It may also rotate or vibrate - two more. The most basic version of this thought process appears in the equipartition theorem. In a system that follows the equipartition theorem, each degree of freedom has an associated heat capacity of $k_B/2$ (per molecule/atom). So, for example, a monoatomic ideal gas has a heat capacity of $3k_B/2$ per atom since there are only three degrees of freedom (isochoric heat capacity, that is). Therefore the specific heat capacity is $3R/2$.
In a solid, you have electronic and phononic contributions to the heat capacity, representing the different "modes" heat may be absorbed. The phononic contribution in particular stirred thought from even Einstein in the well-known Einstein model for solids. Originally the thought was that the specific heat capacity of solids was simply $3R$ (Dulong-Petit law) since it holds for most solids, and it can be derived from equipartition arguments.
But this relationship is only valid for high temperatures - in particular, temperatures around the Debye temperature (from the Debye model). It's observed that heat capacity decreaseas with temperature quite sharply, in accordance to the 3rd law of thermodynamics. The curve goes as $T^{3}$.
Einstein tried to tackle this problem with a naive model. A solid is formed by a large amount of oscillators, all of them at the same frequency, $\omega$. This is a rather harsh simplification, it's a "toy model", really. The average energy of the system can be determined through statistical mechanics - or, more simply, considering the Bose-Einstein distribution for phonons
$$\bar{E}=\hbar \omega \bar{N}=\frac{\hbar \omega}{\exp\left(\frac{\hbar \omega}{kT} \right)-1}.$$
You can arrive at the heat capacity by deriving this expression with respect to $T$. The result is that the heat capacity increases exponentially with temperature. This is "much faster" than expected but it already accounts for the observed phenomena of decreasing heat capacity with temperature.
Debye extended this reasoning into a more complete formalism, assuming that phonons hold a linear dispersion relation $\omega = ck$, that is, there are many frequencies within the solid. Through this thought process you can reach a very, very good $T^3$ prediction for the heat capacity of solids.
Liquids are more complicated systems but methods exist to explain their heat capacity, too. In the case of water, its high heat capacity has to do with the presence of strong intermolecular hydrogen bonds. You need a lot of energy to break them, to excite the water molecules. These bonds also explain the lower density of ice with respect to water. When they form, they keep molecules more separate than they were previously.

Different materials have different mechanisms for storing heat energy. For example, water has very high heat capacity because the heat input is used to pry apart the (weak but numerous) hydrogen bonds that act between adjacent water molecules in the liquid state. For solid metals, heat addition adds vibrational energy to the crystalline lattice of metal atoms that make up the solid, and adds vibrational energy to the motion of the free electrons that roam about the lattice. In (ideal) gases, there is no lattice, no free electrons and no adjacent contact between atoms so the ability to store heat comes about by simply increasing the velocity of the gas atoms as they zoom about between collisions.
